# POSTGRESQL: Cannot log in postgresql in debian 9

Tags: postgresql, debian

I am trying to log in my postgresql.After researching I have solved a slew of many issues from a weird python dependency issue to creating sudoers with names and passwords as db to removing and reinstalling postgresql, still i cannot log in as the default user "postgres".
A simple error but i cannot find a straight forward answer.

```
 Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

NOTE:

1. My first installation,postgresql 11, I changed pg_hba.conf from peer to md5 but refused to login.
2. I removed postgresql 11 using many commands to purge it out of my system but am shocked anytime i do a **locate postgress** or **locate psql** i find a list of postgresql files. The most weird is running **apt-get remove --auto-remove postgresql** and **sudo apt --purge remove postgresql -y** then running **service postgresql start** only for it to start!Cannot wrap my head around this after trying several times, i thought it would be removed completely?!.
3. Though I can **locate pg_hba.conf**, the actual file is totally nonexitent when I **ls** the containing directory!!! Are there many /etc/ folders, seems am looking at the wrong /etc/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem - You try this method, it's work for me.

`If You using Linux then do according your server path` .

Window Path ->

Go To ->  `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\data` then Open `pg_hba.conf`

Find  and replace `md5  or  sha256  to trust`

```
local   replication     all    trust (Change md5 or sha256 to trust)
host    replication     all    trust (Change md5 or sha256 to trust)
```

Maybe this method helpful for you.

Comment: I cannot find pg_hba.conf as i said on point number 3 above even though when i use locate command it shows, its nonexitent..the directory is empty??

Comment: @Afroid1000 I have no idea about Linux server

Comment: Thanks bro for trying

Comment: @Afroid1000 please visit once i hope this link helpful for you https://askubuntu.com/questions/256534/how-do-i-find-the-path-to-pg-hba-conf-from-the-shell

Comment: I have tried them all, unfortunately, all the solutions there depend actually on loggin in your posgresql or at least accessing psql which i cannot due to the error i pasted above. Thanks for replying.